# LDAP Authentication for Ruby on Rails , using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, active-directory, ldap

Need help to make it work , right now it says

```
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

Appreciate any suggestion

ldap.yml

```
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
## Authorization
group_base: : ou=Group, dc=company, dc=com
required_groups:
- cn=proxyagent,ou=profile,dc=company,dc=com
require_attribute:
obectclass=*
authorizationRole: memberuid
attribute: cn

development:
 host: ldap-33.company.com
 port: 389
 attribute: uid
 base: ou=People,dc=company,dc=com; ou=People, ou=mcdata,dc=company,dc=com
 admin_user: cn=proxyagent,ou=profile,dc=company,dc=com
 admin_password: welcome
ssl: true
<<: *AUTHORIZATIONS
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

devise :ldap_authenticatable,:rememberable, :trackable
```

Please show me where I am wrong, correct settings for Splunk are:

```
 Host: ldap-33.company.com
Port: 389
Bind DN: cn=proxyagent,ou=profile,dc=company,dc=com
Bind DB Pass:  welcome
User base DN:ou=People,dc=company,dc=com; ou=People, ou=mcdata,dc=company,dc=com
User base filter:  (objectclass=person)
User name attribute:  uid
Real Name attribute: cn
Group mapping attribute: uid

Group settings:
 Group base DN: ou=Group, dc=company, dc=com
 Group base filter: (obectclass=*)
 Group name attribute: cn
 Group member attribute: memberuid
```

Thank you!

D

Answer (score 0):

In host replace

`ldap-33.company.com`
to `ldap://33.company.com` or `ldap.33.company.com`